# Is there a sufficiently memory-hard asymmetric encryption available?

Tags: public-key, reference-request, memory-hard

The [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net/) offers several memory-hard hashing algorithms that are aware of time memory trade-off and essentially try to make it hard for ASICs and FPGAs to brute-force hashes.

Is there something similar available for asymmetric encryption?

Comment: What properties would a "memory-hard asymmetric encryption" have?  Would it be one where you have to have a lot of memory to encrypt?  Or, do you need a lot of memory (and the private key) to decrypt?

Comment: Using an expensive hash to produce shorter public key finger prints is the only sensible deliberately expensive operation related to asymmetric crypto I can think of.

Comment: @poncho encryption/decryption as far as the regular process go are not quite the intended goal for memory-hard. It's when a third party tries to gain access to what is encrypted, without having any key. Essentially forcing the attacker to need a lot of memory trying to decrypt without access to a key. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Can you clarify what's unclear about my question? AFAIK most asymmetric encryption methods currently focus on making it mostly a CPU bound operation to brute-force the data. But this means that a cluster of FPGAs/ASICs such as the [copacobana](http://www.copacobana.org/) can provide a cost-effective solution for brute-forcing.

Comment: The only reason why we're using expensive password hashes is that users refuse the memorize strong passwords. If users could memorize passwords with 128+ bits of entropy, we wouldn't bother with expensive hashes. When dealing with computers, you can simply use big enough keys to make brute-force infeasible.

Comment: "It's hard to decrypt without the private key if you don't have a lot of memory"; I believe that any secure public key encryption system meets that criteria :-)

Comment: The only case in asymmetric encryption where something like this would be needed is with password-derived keys, e.g. Bitcoin brainwallet. There normal password hashes/PBKDFs (+ perhaps a CSPRNG for e.g. prime generation) solve the problem.

Comment: @CodesInChaos This is a satisfactory answer to my question.